# Integration of a function over a sector of a circle

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Suppose I have an equation in polar form as,
$$f(r,\theta) = 
\begin{cases}
a & x\leq R\\
b\arcsin{\left(\frac{R}{r}\right)} & r>R
\end{cases}$$
The equation is independent of $\theta$. I want to integrate the function over the sector of a circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ with sector being considered from i.e. $\theta_1 \leq \theta \leq \theta_2$. The cartesian coordinates of the sector of circle are as,

$$\mathcal{D} = \{(x,y) \,|\, x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta;  \,\forall\, r \in \mathbb{R}, \theta_1 \leq \theta \leq \theta_2\}$$

The integration is easy in polar cordinates as,
$$I = \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \int_0^r f(r,\theta) r \,{\rm d}r \,{\rm d}\theta$$

This you can easily calculate, now what if I shift my circle i.e., $x^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2$, the sector is also shifted but the arc angle remains same i.e., $\theta_1 \leq \theta \leq \theta_2$. I want to find the the same integral for a shifted sector, where only the origin of sector is shifted in y-axis and the arc angle remains same. I am blank how to approach?. Any help is appreciated